# Counterexample for the Skolem-Noether Theorem

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, division-rings

If a division ring is finite-dimensional over its center then we can apply [Skolem-Noether theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%E2%80%93Noether_theorem) (which asserts that every endomorphism is a conjugation).

Can someone give a counterexample of the Skolem-Noether theorem when the division ring is infinite-dimensional over its center?

Comment: So it's enough to find a division ring and an injective, non-surjective endomorphism. Consider the free group over $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$, and the endomorphism induced by $x_n\mapsto x_{n+1}$. Extend it to an endomorphism of the group ring (over some given field $k$). This is an Ore domain, so I guess this extends to an injective, non-surjective endomorphism of the right division ring of fractions, whose center is reduced to $k$. But I haven't checked details.

Answer (score 6):

The following statement is taken from Cohn's 1995 book *Skew Fields: Theory of General Division Rings* (Cambridge EOM **57**), proposition 2.3.4 on page 69, which is attributed to Köthe:

> Let $k$ be a commutative field with an automorphism $\alpha$ and put $E = k(\!(t;\alpha)\!)$ [the division ring of $\alpha$-twisted Laurent series over $k$].  Given any automorphism $\beta$ of $k$ such that $\alpha\beta = \beta\alpha$, extend $\beta$ to $E$ by the rule $t^\beta = t$.  Then $\beta$ is an inner automorphism of $E$ if and only if $\beta = \alpha^r$ for some $r\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Cohn adds:

> For example, if $k = F(s)$, where $F$ is any field of characteristic $0$, and $\alpha\colon s\mapsto s+1$ the $\beta\colon s\mapsto s+\frac{1}{2}$ is an outer automorphism of $E = k(\!(t;\alpha)\!)$.

For completeness of MathOverflow, let me recall the definition of the division ring $E = k(\!(t;\alpha)\!)$ of $\alpha$-twisted (or "skew") Laurent series: its elements are of the form $\sum_{i=i_0}^{+\infty} t^i c_i$ with $c_i \in k$ [here I'm following Cohn's convention of using right-multiplication by $k$], addition being defined componentwise and multiplication by distributing and using the rule $c t^n = t^n c^{\alpha^n}$ [where, of course, $c^{\alpha^n}$ denotes the image of $c$ under the $n$-th power of $\alpha$].

Comment: As an aged mathematician with failing vision, I add my oft-repeated plaint and request that you not use both $\alpha$ and $a$ in a formula, especially where one of them may appear in superscripts.

Comment: @Lubin Indeed, I normally try to avoid this, but in this particular case I wanted to copy the notation from Cohn's book.  Also, it shouldn't be such a problem on a web page since browsers have a zoom feature; when writing PDF files (where formatting is fixed), I try to keep my fonts large and readable, as I also have a bad eyesight.

Comment: All you say is true, but it surely couldn’t have confused the reader for you to have called the coefficients $c_i$.